# Twitter API - upload an image

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, twitter, tweets

I try to upload an image via [Twitter api](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update_with_media) , as described there I created a form with `name="status"` and `name="media[]"` -

```
<form id="image-form">
    <input type="text" name="status">
    <input name="media[]" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="POST IMAGE">
</form>
```

in addition I have a `submit` handler -

```
   $('#image-form').submit( function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData(this); // <-- 'this' is your form element


        $.ajax({
                    url:'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    pagerocessData: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('Image upload succeeded');
                    },
                    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('GET failed.');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Under Networks at Chrome I see this request with `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`

finally I get "response 200" but it doesn't upload an image to the Twitter account ,

What I did wrong here ?

Comment: From [POST media/upload](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload) : `Ensure your POST is a multipart/form-data request`. Did you do that? (I haven't used twitter's api, but it seems that it might be that)

Comment: Checked and found  - `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`

Comment: Why don't you use the current API hook instead of the deprecated one?

This endpoint has been DEPRECATED. Please use POST statuses/update for uploading one or more media entities.

Answer (score 8):

I couldn't post this as a comment, so I'm going to risk my life writing it as an answer :P.

I tried [Exploring the Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console) (on Firefox works, in Chrome it fails when loading it).

Steps to set up the testing

- **Service** : Select `https://api.twitter.com/1.1`, it will show up some options. In the endpoints list select the one you are using.
- **Authentication** : OAuth (try with a fake account if you are afraid of using your owns, I've created a fake one to test this. I tried with `No auth`, `Basic Auth` and none of them worked)
- **Request URL** : POST, the url is set automatically.
- **Query tab** : `status` - The tweet message.
- **Body tab** : scroll down and look for `media`, select an image.

Finally press `send`.

What I can notice is that if I don't specify an image nor text it will fail (obviously). If I set an image without a status it will upload the image, and if I specify both, well... it will upload the image with the text.

Note that the status is appended to the URL.

So a few questions :

- Did you set up OAuth?
- Are you setting at least one of the required fields (status or media)? Are you passing the status through the URL?
- When you say it works, but it doesn't upload the image, do you see the status in your twitter account?

Here's the result of the [fake account](https://twitter.com/supernamenotuse) I made.

I hope at least it gives you a hint of what it can be.

Comment: what about if I want to send image -media- over image url ?

Comment: Do you have sample javascript for this ?